# Can't Delete HDFS Directory Via Web Interface Because I'm Dr. Who

Tags: hadoop, configuration, permissions, hdfs

I'm trying to delete the directory `deepnlptest/models` on a local HDFS system using the web interface at http://localhost:50070/explorer.html. 
My username is wmcneill and permissions on the HDFS directory I am trying to delete and the enclosing one are `drwxr-xr-x` owned by wmcneill.

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls deepnlptest
17/11/16 09:36:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x   - wmcneill supergroup          0 2017-11-15 17:09 deepnlptest/canonical-folders
drwxr-xr-x   - wmcneill supergroup          0 2017-11-08 14:35 deepnlptest/data
drwxr-xr-x   - wmcneill supergroup          0 2017-11-15 16:51 deepnlptest/embeddings
drwxr-xr-x   - wmcneill supergroup          0 2017-11-15 16:53 deepnlptest/models
drwxr-xr-x   - wmcneill supergroup          0 2017-11-09 10:28 deepnlptest/pretrained_embeddings
```

I get the following error when I try to use the web interface to delete the directory.

[image]

Except for deleting, the web interface works fine for browsing HDFS. I am able to do everything on the HDFS system via the command line command `hdfs dfs` including deleting the directory.

```
$ hdfs dfs -rm -r deepnlptest/models
17/11/16 09:37:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Deleted deepnlptest/models
```

I assume that "dr.who" is a default user and I need to add my username to some Hadoop configuration file, but I can't figure out which one.

I'm running Hadoop 2.8.2 on a Mac installed beneath `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2`.

Comment: check: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/Permission-denied-user-root-access-WRITE-inode-quot-user-quot/td-p/4943

Comment: I don't think that Cloudera link addresses the issue. That describes a case where the end user is not able to delete a root folder owned by the hdfs system. I am trying to delete a subfolder that I own.

Comment: sure you own it? what does `hdfs dfs -ls` of that dir show?

Comment: It looks like I do. I updated the original post with the output of `hdfs dfs -ls`.

Answer (score 2):

When you access the Web UI, you are accessing the cluster as **Dr.Who**, not your user.

*Dr. Who* doesn't have permission to delete in your dir. It is a user to be used for browsing.

```
+------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|                              |           | The user name to filter as,on static web filters   |
| hadoop.http.staticuser.user  |  dr.who   | while rendering content. An example use is the HDFS|
|                              |           | web UI (user to be used for browsing files).       |
+------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Refer: [Who is Dr.Who?](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64743/who-is-drwho.html)

Additional reference: [core-default](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking at this, you can set your user by setting the property in the `core-site.xml` as such

```xml
<configuration>
...
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name>
        <value>youruserhere</value>
    </property>
...
</configuration>
```

That should override the dr.who default user and allow you to delete/upload from the web interface.